# App size is significally bigger than expected?

Tags: android, size, bin

I have almost finished writing my app, and i am concerned about the app size. Besides the **876KB res** folder and the **1,08 MB assets**, the rest of the files in the project are just source code in src (the src is about 80KB). The app can download a ~160KB file from the web. From the app info (in the app settings), says the following:

```
 Total ............5.89MB 
 App ..............1.79MB
 USB Storage app.. 4.09MB
 Data ............12.00KB
 SD Card.......... 0.00 B
```

The app is saved on the SD card.
The question is, is there a way to reduce that size? I have already compressed the images I am using and it seems really weird to me that with the size of the folders in the project, the app needs 6 MB of space.

Also, how come the app size is bigger when the app is in the SD card?

Comment: Are you using any libraries in your app?

Comment: yes, I am using ActionBar Sherlock 4.1 . Does it increase the size that much?

Comment: ActionBar Sherlock adds about 1.2 MB to your app. Are you using any other libraries/library projects like OpenFeint, flurry, admob etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements) in your app. With latest tools, proguard is on by default.
Also, do not consider the size of app until you have obfuscated it.
ActionBarSherlock adds about 200KB to your apk size not MBs.